# How to extract rows of a pandas dataframe according to conditions based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Points':[1,2,3,4,5], 'ColX':[9,8,7,6,5]})
df1
    Points  ColX
0        1     9
1        2     8
2        3     7
3        4     6
4        5     5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Points':[2,5], 'Sum':[-1,1], 'ColY':[2,4]}) # ColY does not matter, I just added it to say that this dataframe can have other columns that the useful columns for this topic
df2
    Points  Sum  ColY
0        2   -1     2
1        5    1     4
```

I would like to get a dataframe with the rows of df1 where :

- the values of column Points in df1 are also in the the column Points of df2
- the values of column Sum in df2 are between 0 and 2

Consequently, I would like to get this dataframe (no matter the index) :

```
    Points  ColX
4        5     5
```

I tried the following but it didn't work :

```
df1[df1.merge(df2, on = 'Points')['Sum'] <= 2 and ['Sum']>=0]
```

Could you please help me to find the right code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1[df1['Points'].isin(df2.query('0 <= Sum <= 2')['Points'])]
```

Output:

```
  Points  ColX
4       5     5
```

Explained:

- `df2.query('0 <= Sum <=2')` to filter df2 first to only valid records
- Then use boolean indexing with `isin` of filter df2 Points column.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution !

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for boolean mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering passed to another mask with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df1[df1['Points'].isin(df2.loc[df2['Sum'].between(0,2), 'Points'])]
print (df)
   Points  ColX
4       5     5
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'Points').query('0<=Sum<=2')[df1.columns]
print (df)
   Points  ColX
1       5     5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Ewdlam - The best way to show thanks is to simply upvote an answer (or select it as the answer, as you've already done.)  The idea is to minimize noise and maximize helpful content.  Otherwise, nearly every post here would have "thanks" comments.  We appreciate your attempt to be polite. :-)

Answer (score 1):

also works:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='Points')
result = df3[(df3.Sum >= 0) & (df3.Sum <= 2)]
result
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !